# No response from urllib3 package as of December 2022

Tags: python, networking, raspi-config

for months I have used my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian version 10 [Buster]) to query different APIs using different python packages (such as [tgtg](https://github.com/ahivert/tgtg-python) or [spotipy](https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy). Everything worked perfectly until the start of this month, were the scripts stopped working all of a sudden.

I can still load and initialize the different objects, but as soon as I try and send a request to the respective API (for example to get a song) nothing happens. When I cancel the command after several minutes I get the following error (regardless of the package).

```py
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 1703, in devices
    return self._get("me/player/devices")
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 297, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 221, in _internal_call
    headers = self._auth_headers()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 212, in _auth_headers
    token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 525, in get_access_token
    token_info = self.validate_token(self.cache_handler.get_cached_token())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 381, in validate_token
    token_info["refresh_token"]
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 586, in refresh_access_token
    timeout=self.requests_timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 358, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 175, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

Because the error is essentially the same, regardless of the package, I think it has something to do with either `urllib3` (I am using version 1.26.13) or `requests` (I am using version 2.21.0). Also, when I try and run the scripts from my laptop, they work perfectly fine..

Does anyone have any pointers what might go wrong? I already tried to update/reinstall the packages and also ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but nothing helped...
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: maybe the problem originates at the internet

Comment: You might be right... when I go to the RPI via a remote desktop connection, I can open the internet and browse pages as usual. But when I try to ping a site, i.e. with `ping google.com` I do not get a response... Do you know what might be the issue?